# In .net5.0 - Extranal API response time takes too long time - httpclient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, timeoutexception, asp.net5

I'm trying to get response a external API using httpclint in .netcore5.0.

Initially I got timeout exception. So I add   `client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;` after adding this response is come. but it takes more than 20 mins.

But I browser I can get API result within milliseconds.

How can I get response from API with a short time. Any idea to decrease this responding time?

startup.cs

```
 services.AddHttpClient<IHolidayService, HolidayService>("PublicHolidaysApi", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.xmltime.com"));
```

service.cs

```
public class HolidayService : IHolidayService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public HolidayService(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
            client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
        }
        public  HolidayService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            _client = clientFactory.CreateClient("PublicHolidaysApi");
        }

        public async Task<Holiday> GetHolidays(string country,int year)
        {
            string url = string.Format($"/holidays?accesskey="MyAccessKey"&secretkey="MySecretKey"&version=3&country=ro&year=2021&lang=en");
            var result = new Holiday();

            using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan))
            {
                var response =  await _client.GetAsync(url, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Holiday>>(responseStream);

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
  return result;
        }
    }
}
```

model

```
 public class Holiday
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("urlid")]
            public string UrliId { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("country")]
            public Country Country { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("name")]
            public Name Name { get; set; }


            [JsonPropertyName("oneliner")]
            public OneLiner OneLiner { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("date")]
            public Date Date { get; set; }


            [JsonPropertyName("types")]
            public List<string> Types { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("uid")]
            public string UId { get; set; }

        }


        public class Country
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }

        public class Name
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("lang")]
            public string Lang { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
        public class OneLiner
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("lang")]

            public string Lang { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }

        }
        public class Date
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("iso")]
            public string iso { get; set; }

            [JsonPropertyName("datetime")]
            public DateTime? Datetime { get; set; }

        }
}
```

Comment: can you attach your model as well?  and please do not share API keys. and there are compile-time errors in your code, you are creating a result variable which is Holiday type but you are trying to assign List<Holiday>.

Comment: Works fast on my machine =). How often do you call this API?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possibilities in this situation and I can only give you a way to solve the problem.

First of all, we need to locate the reason why it is so slow. Is it the server or the client?

We can use packet capture tools such as `Fiddler` ,and then observe the corresponding network requests.

If client had send but server not response , you should think about the api limit...
And if not, the request are not send at all, may be you should the check the connection pool of the HttpClient, or the `WorkThreadPool` of dotnet.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with your question.

1. it doesn't compile.
2. it is incomplete.
3. it has sensitive data.

but I can get the data from API in no time. just open this link https://dotnetfiddle.net/ryjakT and run the program.

I changed few things

1. Return Type, it should be List
2. var result = new Holiday(); to var result = new List();
3. I am using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for Deserialization.
4. you were trying to Deserialize to an incorrect model, it should be Root.

Comment: Thank you manish, When I use your code It give Timeout exception. Then I add `  client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;`. After added this line It works. But It takes around 10 mins to get response.

Comment: This is my service ` public class HolidayService : IHolidayService
    {

        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public HolidayService(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
            client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
        }
      public async Task <List<Holiday>> GetHolidays(){
         // your code 
       } 
    }`

Comment: I think some issue with your network, I try this code in fiddler and in my local environment, it completes its execution within seconds.  but the main issue is we can't tell exactly until we saw the whole system.

Comment: Or just try to monitor the traffic using Fiddler, I think the issue is related to network or the API (there could be chances if you are hitting this API more frequently it can block you for some time)

Comment: just try to create a small git repo and your non-sensitive code there so that we can have more clarity on this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my github repository. https://github.com/Thanusiga/holiday-web-api-.net5.0

Comment: I investigated the code and tried in my local, it seemed to be working fine for me. it is responding within a second. The issue is with your network.

Comment: Okay manish. Thank you for your great help.

Comment: Hi manish. I am facing an issue updating Database using EF. If you don't mind could you please help me.. This is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69484924/issue-while-updating-parent-database-table-child-table-not-updating-in-ef

Comment: @hanu could you please mark this question as answered?