# Could not update child table while parent table updating in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have 4 tables.
parent - Enquiry,
Children tables -
EnquiryCustomer, EnquiryFlights, EnquiryHotels.

I can create a new Enquiry successfully (all table are updated with new enquiry data).

I am facing issue, when I update a enquiry. The parent table is successfully updated. **But can not update the child tables**

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "enquiryType": 3,
    
    "customers": {
         "id": 7,
        "customerName": " updated updated",
        "enquiryId": 3
    },
    "flights": {
        "id": 7,
        "enquiryId": 3,
        "departureAirportId": 9,
        "arrivalAirportId": 2
    },
    "hotels": {
        "id": 7,
        "hotelLocation": "location updated updated",
        "enquiryId": 3
    }
}
```

- This is my data for update. (I use same data without id, enquiryId for POST It works(row created))
- When PUT this json requst,   `"enquiryType": 3,` this is updated. BUT children did not upadte.

The result is

```
{
    "message": "Site Enquiry updated",
    "enquiry": {
        "id": 3,
        "enquiryType": 3,

        "customers": null,
        "flights": null,
        "hotels": null
    }
}
```

- After this update, If I put again same json request (without childern's ids) All tables are updated)

I have no idea why this issue occur? anyone help me to find the problem.

These are the codes I used

Equiry.ts model

```
 public class Enquiry
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public EnquiryType EnquiryType { get; set; }

        public EnquiryCustomer Customers { get; set; }

        public EnquiryFlight Flights { get; set; }

        public EnquiryHotel Hotels { get; set; }

    }

    public class EnquiryCustomer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public Enquiry Enquiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EnquiryId { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnquiryHotel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string HotelLocation { get; set; }

        public Enquiry Enquiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EnquiryId { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnquiryFlight
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int DepartureAirportId { get; set; }

        public Departure DepartureAirport { get; set; }

        public Enquiry Enquiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EnquiryId { get; set; }

    }
```

EnquiryViewModel

```
 public class EnquiryViewModel
    {

        [Required]
        public EnquiryType EnquiryType { get; set; }

        public EnquiryCustomer Customers { get; set; }

        public EnquiryFlight Flights { get; set; }

        public EnquiryHotel Hotels { get; set; }

    }

    public class EnquiryCustomer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public EnquiryViewModel Enquiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EnquiryId { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnquiryHotel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string HotelLocation { get; set; }

        public EnquiryViewModel Enquiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EnquiryId { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnquiryFlight
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int DepartureAirportId { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public int ArrivalAirportId { get; set; }

        public EnquiryViewModel Enquiry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EnquiryId { get; set; }
    }
```

EnquiryController.cs

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] EnquiryViewModel enquiry)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _enquiryService.Get(id);

                if (result == null)
                {
                    return NotFound(new { message = "Site Enquiry not found" });
                }


                _mapper.Map<EnquiryViewModel, Enquiry>(enquiry, result);  // mapping works fine

                await _enquiryService.Update(result);

                return Ok(new { message = "Site Enquiry updated", enquiry = result });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
```

Service.cs

```
  public async Task<int> Update(Enquiry enquiry)
        {
            _catalogDbContext.Enquirys.Update(enquiry); // untill this line all works fine

            return await _catalogDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // after the Database updates Childern's data change as `null`
        }
```

dBContext.cs

```
     public DbSet<Enquiry> Enquirys { get; set; }

        public DbSet<EnquiryCustomer> EnquiryCustomer { get; set; }

        public DbSet<EnquiryHotel> EnquiryHotel { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<EnquiryFlight> EnquiryFlight { get; set; }
```

The childern's data change to null at this line `return await _catalogDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`

Anyone can find the problem?

Comment: Why you call `_catalogDbContext.Enquirys.Update(enquiry)` at all? EF tracks changes in objects automatically.

Comment: I don't call that line. yeah I remove that line now. But My issue is not solve yet. DO you have any idea Why child response as null when update

Comment: If you want to update `Children`, You have to use `Include(x => Children)` in `Get` method.